# How to add int to argv

Tags: python-2.7, argv

How do I add 'int' to this code so that at least one of the three has to be an integer?

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script

print "Your first variable is:", first

print "Your second variable is:", second

print "Your third variable is:", third
```

Comment: Can you rephrase that? What do you mean by add int? If the arguements are integers, then you can do what @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams sugested. Other than that, I don't understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You do it separately.

```
second = int(second)
```